# rendered attribute on inputText

Tags: jsf

I have a search form tied to a backing bean that contains 4 input text fields.  The design i am working from indicates that the user should be able to see the search results, but they should not be editable.  i decided to use the rendered attribute to show the inputs if the managed bean is empty, and to show an output text tag if it's not:

```
<t:inputText styleClass="inputText" id="name" rendered="#{not searchCriteria.fieldsEntered}"
value="#{searchCriteria.name}" autocomplete="off"></t:inputText>
<h:outputText value="#{searchCriteria.name}" rendered="#{searchCriteria.fieldsEntered}"></h:outputText>
```

The display part works correctly, but I am noticing that only the first field is stored in the managed bean when more than 1 search field is entered.

I removed a rendered attribute from an inputText, and sure enough that's causing my problems.  I can infer what's going on here, but I don't understand why.

I believe in this situation I will just remove the outputText tags and change rendered to disabled.  I am just curious why my initial plan is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `rendered="false"` will cause the input element not being rendered and thus its value will not be submitted to the server side. If you're using a request scoped bean, the initial value will not be set. You'd like to either put the bean in session scope or to add a `h:inputHidden` along the `h:outputText` which transfers the value to the subsequent request.

Since you're already using [Tomahawk's `t:inputText`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_inputText.html) I'd suggest to rather use its `displayValueOnly` attribute instead of the `rendered` attribute and a complementary `h:outputText`.

In a nut:

```
<t:inputText displayValueOnly="#{searchCriteria.fieldsEntered}" ... />
```